# Problems with using ginput for a mouse over function

Tags: matlab, mouseevent, mouseover

I'm trying to develop code for a mouse over function. What I need are the following.

1.) To be able to change to a small crosshair cursor if the mouse is within the bounds of a plot and change back to an arrow if it is outside the bounds of a plot.

2.) Be able to click and plot the point within the plot bounds and keep the small crosshair for the cursor type.

I got the first requirement to work. I am having problems with the second. I'm trying to to use the modified ginput function myginput from mathworks. Within the myginput function, I changed the function to myginput() and set arg1 == 1 and set strpointertype = 'Crosshair'.

From within the function I am creating mouseover.m, within the if/else statement to check if the cursor is within the plot bounds I set the ButtonDownFcn to call myginput. If I run the program and try to click within the plot bounds, I get an error using @myginput, "Too many input arguments". I'm not using any input arguments since I already specified them in the myginput function.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this? The main GUI calls the mouseover function by

```
set (gcf, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @mouseover);
```

and the axes handles for plotting is plot_data. So just make a dummy GUI (alpha) with a plot having a tag plot_data and set a global variable within this GUI.

```
function varargout = alpha_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
global plot_data


% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;

% now attach the function to the axes
set(gca,'ButtonDownFcn', @mouseclick)


set (gcf, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @mouseover);
```

Here is my code below for the mouseover.m function

```
function [data] = mouseover(gcbo,eventdata,handles)
global plot_data


cp = get(gca,'Position');           %get postion data of the current axes

LeftBound = cp(1);
RightBound = LeftBound + cp(3);

LowerBound = cp(2);
UpperBound = LowerBound + cp(4);

%check to see if mouse is within the bounds of the axes
in_bounds = @(mx, my) LeftBound < mx && mx < RightBound && LowerBound < my && my < UpperBound;

mp = get(gcf, 'CurrentPoint');      %get current position of mouse

if in_bounds(mp(1,1),mp(1,2)) == 1
    set(gcf,'pointer','Crosshair');
    set(gca,'ButtonDownFcn', @myginput)
else
    set(gcf,'pointer','Arrow');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to myginput available in the file exchange at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12770, it does not look like it is written for use as a callback. A callback function for ButtonDownFcn should always take two input arguments. They are src and eventData. See the documentation for function handle callbacks at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/function-handle-callbacks.html. You can try defining your own function which takes the required two inputs and then call myginput from within that function.

Comment: I've actually just started work on my own function. I made a mouseover function and if the cursor is within the bounds of the plot, the selectpoint function is called. I just need to add in functionality for deleting a point. I just need to figure out how to determine if a clicked point is near any other points already plotted.